# SQLalchemy-Flask: ArgumentError for one to many relationship

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use sqlalchemy to run queries for one to many relationship. I am having trouble getting my queries to run.

```
class Quote(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    category = db.Column(db.String(100))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    quote_cat = db.relationship("Quote", backref='category', lazy=True)
    quote_id_ = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('quote.id'))
```

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class Category->category
>   could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'category'

Comment: I get `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'category' on relationship 'Category.quote_cat': property of that name exists on mapper 'mapped class Quote->quote'`

Answer (score 0):

Your quote_cat `backref` references a property that already exists on the `Quote` class. Either remove this or change the `backref` value.

Here are the [`backref`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.backref) docs:

> - backref –
>
> indicates the string name of a property to be placed on the related mapper’s class that will handle this relationship in the other direction